# What units in a boolean type?

Tags: units-of-measurement

This is almost a joke question -- I'm about to assign a value of "boolean" to a unit of measure to denote that the associated variable is true or false.  But that's unsatisfying for a variable that otherwise would take on the value of "degrees" or "volts", etc.

So:

Units of length are inches or meters or cubits, etc.

Units of angle are degrees, minutes, seconds, or gradians, or the oh-so-natural radians.

Units within an exponent (i.e. e^x) are Napirs (really!)

But what are the units of the true/false, 0/1, etc. of a Boolean variable?  Veracitons?

Comment: booleans doesn't have any inherent unit, so it's up to you for any particular problem. It could be the number of elephants - e.g, you either have no elephant (false) or 1 elephant(true) - albeit you'd rather use it foe something that would always be one or zero (on/off, present/not present, taken/not taken, enabled/disabled, done/not done ... )

Answer (score 0):

Not everything has a unit. Ratios don't have units, for example. Pi doesn't have a unit. Some things are just numbers.

If you're trying to assign units to a boolean value, or rather as you say "assigning a boolean value to a unit", then I suspect there's another way of doing it. Surely your variable is either zero units or some (true) units?

Comment: Radian is the SI unit for angle. Saying pi doesn't have an inherent unit is like saying the number 2 doesn't: true but unrelated.  I think you mean to use radian as an example of a "dimensionless unit".  This always seemed like an awkward detail of SI to me, e.g. angular velocity and hertz have the same unit notation yet you need to multiple one by 2pi to get the other.

Answer (score 0):

Units are generally related to physical measurements.  I suspect that if this question makes sense, the answer is dimensionless.

My intuition here is that probabilities "should" be a generalization of booleans and that probabilities are generally a ratio -- e.g. how certain are you that there is an elephant in this room?  I checked 100 times and every time except once, the elephant was there.  Thus I predict you'll observe an elephant to be in the room approximately 99 measurements / 100 measurements.

"measurement" here might be in units of elephants, but the certainty (or probability, confidence, truth value, or whatever you want to call it) is dimensionless.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant